# Does $_GET['param_name'] potentially trouble maker with array returning?

Tags: php, arrays, get

I'm new to PHP and this question seems stupid.

But I'm really confused with the associative array $_GET, which can help me access the all parameters that has been sent via URL.

Suppose I'm expecting a string of product_ID, and write in the code like this :

```
$id = $_GET['prod_id'];
Get_Data($id);
```

While Get_Data() is a function that expects the only parameter to be string, but not array.
What if some bad guy type in the url something like this :

```
.../product.php?prod_id[]=1&prod_id[]=2
```

The method using `$_GET['prod_id']` will return an array(1,2) instead of a string. This can lead to some really bad trouble in my application.

Now, the question : Is there a global way to avoid the case above ?

---

**[EDIT]**

Sometimes I want to get array from `$_GET['prod_id']` instead of string (ex: getting data from a multi-selectbox, where users can pick more than 1 product)

Is it feasible for me to check if the returning array is in correct structure (1 dimensional array, with innocent data) or has been cheated by some bad guy like this :

```
.../product.php?prod_id[a]=1&prod_id[b]=2&prod_id[c]=3&prod_id[d]=4
```

I think it's very easy to pass an array with complex structure to php $_GET, but very hard for coder to check if it's the correct structure they needed.

Can you please enlighten me? Thanks !

Comment: In technical terms, if someone did hack up the url to change that param into array notation, you'd be passing an array to your function. Depending on how you use that value, it might be auto-converted to a string that simply says `Array`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: Validation

One usually use the `filter_input()` function.

https://www.php.net/filter

If sometimes you want it to be an array, use a condition `if (is_array($_GET['prod_id']))` and use different set of validations.

Comment: Really really thank you ! You led me from a narrow path to the highway!

Answer (score 3):

If an array was submitted in the URL, then when retrieved via `$_GET`, it will be a PHP array rather than a string that looks like a serialized array.

```
// Inside a form performing a get request:
// [] on a name makes it an array:
<input type='checkbox' name=arr[] value='chk1' />
<input type='checkbox' name=arr[] value='chk2' />

// Dumps an array, rather than a serialized string
print_r($_GET['arr']);
```

So in your first case:

```
$id = $_GET['prod_id'];
Get_Data($id);
```

### Always validate your input data:

You should be validating the contents of `$id` to be within the bounds you expect, and if you try to use it as a string when it is really an array, the functions acting on it will throw warnings or errors.  Since PHP is weakly typed, a function expecting an integer will happily run if you pass it an array, but will likely crash and burn with errors all over your logs or the screen.

```
// Make sure $id is an int
if (!ctype_digit($id)) {
  // invalid data, abort!
}
```

On the other hand, if the value is expected to be an array:

```
if (!is_array($_GET['prod_id'])) {
  // it wasn't an array, abort!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = str($_GET['prod_id']);
```

That typecasts the variable as a string literal.

Comment: It seems that he wants to validate the array and its values, not try to cast.

Comment: Yea, re-reading OP's post makes me think the same thing. I think Michael has the answer he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Use validation, something like this:

```
$id = (!isset($_GET['prod_id'])) ? null : $_GET['prod_id'];
if (intval($id) > 0) {
   //...
}
#OR
if (is_int($id) > 0) {
  //...
}
```